# Black screen sending push type =3 in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

When I sending push type = 3 the method public void push(final String message) it execute first that init () and my screen does not load and stay black screen. Could you help me?

This just occur if my app it never is open. As you know when the app is in background the OS received the message and when the use press the notification it deliver to my app.

3 - 1 + 2 = 3 allows combining a visual push with a non-visual portion. Expects a message in the form: This is what the user won’t see;This is something he will see. E.g. you can bundle a special ID or even a JSON string in the hidden part while including a friendly message in the visual part.
When active this will trigger the push(String) method twice, once with the visual and once with the hidden data.

http://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html#push-message-types-section

Answer (score 0):

An event can arrive before the UI is ready. If you trigger an exception due to that the UI won't be reached. You need to guard against such cases and store the event for later processing.

Comment: There is a way to launch a specific form from the push notification type=3?

Comment: This issue it just occur in android side. In ios it work perfectly

Comment: These are OS native features, there is a limit to what we can do in terms of abstraction